# asp.net mvc4 two differend views for one action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need two differend views for Kaminy/KaminniTopky & Kaminy/KaminniTopky/5.
How can I do it in that way?

```
public class KaminyController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Kaminy/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: /Kaminy/KaminniTopky
    public ActionResult KaminniTopky()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: /Kaminy/KaminniTopky/5
    public ActionResult KaminniTopky(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need one method with a nullable parameter `public ActionResult KaminniTopky(int? id)` and then you can use `if(id.HasValue)` to determine which view you want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stephen Muecke's idea has merit, you can combine as:

```
public ActionResult KaminniTopky(int? id)
{
   if (!id.HasValue)
   {
      return View();
   }
   else
   {
      return View("OtherViewName");
   }
}
```

There are overloads that take the model too - `return View(someModel);` and `return View("OtherViewName", someModel);` respectively.

In **MVC 5** you could:

```
[Route("Kaminy/KaminniTopky")] 
public ActionResult KaminniTopky()
{
    return View();
}

[Route("Kaminy/KaminniTopky/{id}")] 
public ActionResult KaminniTopky(int id)
{
    return View("OtherViewName");
}
```

---

For something like `/Kaminy/KaminniTopky/KaminniTopkyWithOther/5` you would use routing rather than a weird controller structure to support other style URLs.

E.g. In `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "SomeRoute",
            "/Kaminy/KaminniTopky/KaminniTopkyWithOther/{id}",
            new { controller = "Kaminy", action = "KaminniTopkyWithOther", id = "" }
        );
```

Make sure this comes before the default route.

Then it doesn't matter what your action is called as long as its the same as defined in the route.

```
public ActionResult KaminniTopkyWithOther(int id)
{
    return View("OtherViewName");
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion will throw an exception as soon as the user tries to navigate to it

Comment: Now I just feel like ive stolen your answer :-\ this is what happens when i stack without coffee!

Comment: Thanks,
Also I have another question.
How can I create controllers to support this path.
For example:
/Kaminy/KaminniTopky/KaminniTopkyWithOther/5

Comment: You would need to add that into routing

Comment: Also your last answer help me with new solution for root question:

I did:
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ShowKaminy",
                url: "Kaminy/KaminniTopky/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Kaminy", action = "Show" }
            );
And add in Kaminy controller:
public ActionResult Show(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

And now this URL is valid : Kaminy/KaminniTopky/2